# Trying to get a (If statement) variable finder to work... (JSON Parsed Data) (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

So My `if (Players.PlayerData.AccountActive = 1)` does not work it says
there is an error at the equal sign.
And sending back an error of `Cannot set property of .AccountActive of undefined.`
The Data is already parsed with `require`

```
client.on('message', message => {


    if (message.content.toLowerCase() ==='smack activate') {
        
        let PlayerData = [message.author.username][0];

        Activate [message.author.username] = {
        AccountActive: 1,
        Health: 100,
        Level: 1,
        Lust: 0,
        Items: ""
        };

        if (Players.PlayerData.AccountActive = 1) {
            message.channel.send ("Account Already Activated");
            return;
        };

        fs.writeFile("./Database/Players.json", JSON.stringify (Activate, null, 4), err => {
            if (err) throw err;
            message.channel.send ("Account Activated")
        });
    };
};
```

Players.json

```
{
    "♡Yuzi♡": {
        "AccountActive": 1,
        "Health": 100,
        "Level": 1,
        "Lust": 0,
        "Items": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: `=` assignment, `==` equals, `===` strict equals. You probably want `===`. For starters

Comment: I tried === but returns Cannot read property of AccountActive of underfined

Answer (score 0):

You might consider working with the PlayerData variable that you defined, and validate it to make sure it's not undefined:

```
client.on('message', message => {

if (message.content.toLowerCase() ==='smack activate') {
    
    let PlayerData = [message.author.username][0];

    Activate [message.author.username] = {
    AccountActive: 1,
    Health: 100,
    Level: 1,
    Lust: 0,
    Items: ""
    };

    if (PlayerData && PlayerData.AccountActive === 1) {
        message.channel.send ("Account Already Activated");
        return;
    };

    fs.writeFile("./Database/Players.json", JSON.stringify (Activate, null, 4), err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        message.channel.send ("Account Activated")
    });
};
```

};